# Explain this short SQL query to me please

Tags: sql

```
 "SELECT * from posts A, categories B where A.active='1' 
  AND A.category=B.CATID order by A.time_added desc 
  limit $pagingstart, $config[items_per_page]";
```

I think it says selects the rows from the 'posts' table such that the active entry in each row is equal to 1 but I don't understand the rest. Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It selects the columns from Posts (referred to with the alias "A"), and the associated for from Categories (referred to as "B") for each post, where:

- Posts.Active = 1
- The post's category exist in the "Categories" table (if a post doesn't have a matching category in this table, the row won't be returned)
- Orders the results by A.Time_added (in decending order, newest to oldest)
- Returns just "$config[items_per_page]" rows, starting with "$pagingstart"

I'm not sure what brand of SQL this is, as I don't recognize the limit statement or the $variables, but that's the gist.

Comment: The $ stuff could be PHP or something?

Comment: A and B are aliases so that you don't have to type out posts and categories.  Saves some keystrokes!

Comment: Don't forget "AND A.category=B.CATID", only returns rows where A.category exists in the CATID column of table B

Comment: You should mention that the tables are not named A and B, those are aliases for tables posts and categories.

Comment: And in most DB's this will be populated as INNER JOIN, but this is a guess that asker use "popular" DB engine ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, all - I've expanded my answer to include these points.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get rows

- from A and B that where category and CATID match ("intersection" bit of a Venn Diagram)
- The rows for A are filtered to those where Active = 1
- sorted by time_added. latest first
- limit says y rows startig at row x. x and y are determined by the sort

Answer (score 1):

`posts A, categories B` is a such called "implicit `JOIN`". It returns all possible combinations of records from `A` and `B` which are later filtered by the `WHERE` conditions.

Explicit join syntax is much more readable:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    posts A
JOIN    categories B
ON      B.CATID = A.category
WHERE   A.active='1' 
ORDER BY
        A.time_added DESC
LIMIT   $pagingstart, $config[items_per_page]
```

This means: "for each record from `A`, take all records from `B` whose `catid` is the same as `A`'s category".

`ORDER BY A.time_added DESC` makes your posts to return from latest to earliest.

`LIMIT 100, 10` makes the query to return only posts from `100th` to `110th`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is trying to select all active posts, order them with the newest at the top, and limit the number of records to fit on a page. The semantics of `A.active='1'` *probably* mean that the post is active, but I'm guessing.

It looks like MySQL with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This selects entries from `posts` and `categories`, joining them together where `posts.category=categories.CATID`.  It filters out all rows where `posts.active!=1`, and then orders by descending `posts.time_added`, returning at most `$config[items_per_page]`  items starting from `$pagingstart`.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all the active posts (and their category), newest first. However, it has a paging mechanism, so it shows only `$config[items_per_page]` posts starting at number `$pagingstart`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the rows from the posts table and the categories table, joined into a single table by the category ID (using what I call a lazy join, but that may just be my opinion and I'm not really a database guy), sorted in descending order by the time added, displaying only $items_per_page records starting at $pagingstart.

Answer (score 0):

It select all columns from table posts and categories where posts.active is equal 1 and where **posts.category is joined to the categories.catid**  and this is ordered by posts.time_added  a limit start and end is set by the two variables $pagingstart, $config[items_per_page]

Answer (score 0):

It's saying:

1) Select everything from both `Posts` & `Categories` where `Posts.Active = 1` and `Posts.Category = Category.CATID`.  
2) The `Order by` statement then specifies that they should be presented (from top to bottom) with the newest `Post.Time_Added` first.  
3) Finally, the `limit` clause says (I think, I don't use `limit` very often): Only grab `$spagingstart` (a variable which has been set at some point) number of items, and only display `$config[items_per_page]` at a time.